# How to generate all combinations of letters in a word?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, concatenate, regexextract

Using Google Sheets, how would I show all possible ways to type a word, for example:

```
word
Word
WOrd
WORd
WORD
wOrd
woRd
worD
```

without any length word?
The given word would go on Row A and the possible combinations would go in Row B.

Comment: You are aware your list is missing eight combinations (`2^4 = 16`) and that this list will get *very* long with longer words?

Comment: yes i'm aware i didnt add ALL the possible combinations, it was just to give an example.

and NO i cant open excel 1st and then try and convert the VBA code so if you are able to tell me how to perform this in google sheets which im very new to that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you type your word by one character per cell with lowercase and then type it again with uppercase like this:

[image: 0]

you could use this formula in **F1** cell which will construct you with all possible states:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(REGEXEXTRACT(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(B1:B)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(B1:B, B1:B<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(A1:A))),CHAR(9)))&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(C1:C)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(C1:C, C1:C<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(B1:B)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(B1:B, B1:B<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(A1:A))),CHAR(9)))))),CHAR(9)))&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(D1:D)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(D1:D, D1:D<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(B1:B)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(B1:B, B1:B<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(A1:A))),CHAR(9)))&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(C1:C)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(C1:C, C1:C<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(B1:B)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(B1:B, B1:B<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(A1:A))),CHAR(9)))))),CHAR(9)))))),CHAR(9)))&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(E1:E)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(E1:E, E1:E<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(A1:A&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(B1:B)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(B1:B, B1:B<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(A1:A))),CHAR(9)))&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(C1:C)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(C1:C, C1:C<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(B1:B)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(B1:B, B1:B<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(A1:A))),CHAR(9)))))),CHAR(9)))&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(D1:D)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(D1:D, D1:D<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(B1:B)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(B1:B, B1:B<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(A1:A))),CHAR(9)))&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(C1:C)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(C1:C, C1:C<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(REPT(CONCATENATE(FILTER(A1:A, A1:A<>"")&CHAR(9)),COUNTA(B1:B)),CHAR(9)))&
 TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(REPT(FILTER(B1:B, B1:B<>"")&CHAR(9),COUNTA(A1:A))),CHAR(9)))))),CHAR(9)))))),CHAR(9)))))),CHAR(9))),"^([^-]+)"))
```

[image: 0]

---

**note:** for a word with less then 5 characters use single dashes (**`-`**) only within the first row:

[image: 0]

---

## **for 12 characters:** **[spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qRNRdPVDTo-vox07m8Qewbpd9_meskqGVO2qsyR7ew0/copy)**

## **formula [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1b7VpeIffA0Y9lY4E-kQDhLsVc2WOcheD/view?usp=sharing)**

[image: 0]

---

## for 15 characters: [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1o-XAMwR7oeLowqjqykHGYwNqoptWzX3XPLiepIpgcUw/copy)

[image: 0]

Comment: what about for a word longer than 5 characters ?
is there a way to do this any make it work for say anything up to 12 characters ?

it works great so thanks for that but it needs to be able to accommodate larger words.

Comment: how did you go user0 ?

Comment: WOW that's amazing thanks...
do you know if there is any kind of website that can generate this kind of results without having to use a spreadsheet... im REALLY appreciate ll your help buy just wondering if there is an easier wow because that is some amazing but HUGE code

Comment: what if i wanted to be able use numbers or special characters like ! or _ for instance.. would that be possible ??

Comment: not aware of any site. as for the characters, you can use any characters you wish. also, you may use more than 2 rows. if the spreadsheet stops due to huge formula I have may a solution with hidden helper columns

Comment: **fun fact:** you are allowed to enter only up to 50000 characters as per one formula. this formula has 323461 characters!

Comment: WOW user0 you are amazing... but like you predicted it keeps crashing or freezing due to huge outcome... i did notice though that if i use something like
#12_ then #34_ then _12# then _34# the # symbol and the _ never seem to move only the 12 and the 34 get varied... i may have to install excel again :(

how would you code this for excel ?? im guessing it would be easier just to use VBA for this, but it also needs to be able to have all the characters move not only the numbers.... i hope this makes sense.

Comment: @WiiliamBonney answer updated. try the last sheet - should be fast and without lags and up to 15 character words

Comment: The epic 300K characters formula by simple `Ctrl+H`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55070275/10789707 Thanks!